# Jqgrid (Jquery 3.3.1): Cannot read property 'getAccessor' of undefined

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I'm migrating my application (that works fine) to include authentication feature from VS community 2017. This makes me use Jquery 3.3.1 (instead of 1.11.1) with my jqGrid 3.5. 
The drid works fine, loads data properly, sorts fine. But, when I use the filterToolBar to search data, it doesn't work, it just hung at 'Loading...' and fires the message below in the console window:
[image]

Here is my grid:
[image]

My HTML code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Catégorie Demandeurs (Liste des)";
    }
    <title></title>

    <link href="../content/css/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <!-- Custom Theme files -->
    <link href="../content/css/style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    @*<script src="../content/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>*@
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../content/css/flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <!--webfonts-->
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Julius+Sans+One' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,400,300,600,700|Six+Caps' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
    <!--//webfonts-->
    @*<script type="text/javascript" src="../content/js/bootstrap.js"></script>*@
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0-alpha.4/handlebars.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td align="right">
                @* *** Fermer la fenêtre courante *** *@
                @Html.ActionLink("Fermer", null, null, null, new { @class = "btn btn-primary", id = "close" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div style="float:left; width:100%">
                @* *** Contrôle text caché permet d'envoyer la table choisie *@
                <input type="hidden" id="nomTableHidden" data-value="@ViewBag.Title" />
                <h2>Ajouter/Modifier/Suprimer une Catégorie de Demandeur</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br />
        <br />
        <!-- ******************* Lignes pour le table JQGrid *************************************** -->
        <div style="padding-top: 10px" , class="row">
            <table id="grilleJqGrid_Demandeur_Categorie" style="width: 100%"></table>
            <div id="pager_Demandeur_Categorie"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    @* *** Boutons d'action cachés pour Ajouter/Modifier/Supprimer un enregistrement *** *@
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnAjouterDemandeur_Categorie" style="display: none;"
            onclick="AfficherModales_MenuAdmin($('#fenModAdm_Ajouter_CategoriesDemandeurs'), 'Demandeur_Categorie', null, 'Ajouter')">
        Ajouter une catégorie de demandeur
    </button>
    @Html.Partial("../Adimin_Modales/MenuAdmin_ModalAjouter_Demandeur_Categorie").
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnModifierDemandeur_Categorie" style="display: none;"
            onclick="AfficherModales_MenuAdmin($('#fenModAdm_Modifier_CategoriesDemandeurs'), 'Demandeur_Categorie', this.id, 'Modifier')">
        Modifier une catégorie de demandeur
    </button>
    @Html.Partial("../Adimin_Modales/MenuAdmin_ModalModifier_Demandeur_Categorie")
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSupprimerDemandeur_Categorie" style="display: none;"
            onclick="AfficherModales_MenuAdmin($('#fenModAdm_Supprimer_CategoriesDemandeurs'), 'Demandeur_Categorie', null, 'Supprimer')">
        Supprimer une catégorie de demandeur
    </button>
    @Html.Partial("../Adimin_Modales/MenuAdmin_ModalSupprimer_Demandeur_Categorie")

    <!-- ******************* Début lignes pour la table JQGrid *************************************** -->
    <link href="../Content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/jquery.jqGrid/ui.jqgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="../Scripts/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
    <!-- ******************* Fin lignes pour la table JQGrid *************************************** -->

    @* ********** Custom ref files ********** *@
    <!-- ******************* Script pour le modal *************************************** -->
    <script src="../Scripts/JqGrid_Scripts/ModalForms.js"></script>
    <!-- ******************* Fin script pour le modal *************************************** -->
    <!-- Référence pour les grilles -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/JqGrid_Scripts/AdminForms.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Content/css/css_custom/Admin_CRUD.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/CustomJS/Admin_CRUD.js"></script>
    @* ********** Fin custom ref files ************ *@
</body>
</html>
```

[image: JqGrid 5.3.1 table]

[image: Errors using JqGrid 5.3.1]

Comment: Are you sure hat you use jqGrid 3.5? It's 5 years old. I don't see any jQuery UI CSS in your code. Instead of that you include Bootstrap CSS only (it's unclear which version).

Comment: "In order to use jqGrid 3.5, first a UI theme css file should be loaded..."
That's what the "install" file says.  I've got that version from GitHub site and it says to be the latest free version.
Beside in my version, I can't find any file referring to jQuery UI CSS that you are mentioning and is also mentioned in the "install" file that I have:
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="path_to_ui_css_file/jquery-ui-1.7.1.custom.css" />

Comment: Look at [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) for free jqGrid 4.15.3. If you want to use it without jQuery UI CSS (only with Bootstrap), see [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#bootstrap). If you want to use it with Bootstrap 4 instead of Bootstrap 3.x, then you should use `guiStyle: "bootstrap4"` instead of `guiStyle: "bootstrap"`.

Comment: Upon what you just said, I have downloaded from http://www.trirand.com what seems to be version 5.3.1 
- I'm puzzled and scared about the note: "Note that this is a commercial product and and the download is 30 days trial."
- The grid will show (screenshot 4) but I get those errors (See screenshot 3) a "Warning" window from nowhere, search fields are no longer accessible and so on....

Comment: Look at [the old post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438), which announced the end of "jqGrid" under MIT/GPL licenses at the version 4,7 and renaming the product to **commercial** product "Guriddo jqGrid JS", which license and price you find [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334). Short after the announcement I started fork of jqGrid .4.7 and developed it under the name "free jqGrid" on [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid). It has many new features (see the wiki and READMEs), but one can use it under old MIT/GPL licenses completely free of charge.